# Why french accents are not represented correctly after Matlab2011b?

Tags: matlab, ascii, non-ascii-characters, utf, french

I am mantaining a piece of software developed on Matlab R2011b which uses several languages, french among them.

I am now compiling the code on Matlab R2022 and the non ASCII characters are represented either as  or some other strange symbol.

However this does not happen when I run the code directly from the Matlab IDE, only running the executabl.

Menu after compiling:

[image: Menu after compiling]

Menu when running the code from the IDE:

[image: Menu when running the code from the IDE]

When I run `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` on my command bar it says 'UTF-8', but I', not sure if that is relevant. I tried running some variations of this command, but it had no effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I feel like this might be better asked on the [MathWorks forums](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index/?s_tid=gn_mlc_an) – have you tried there?